# Problem with calling native API from C# on x64 Platform

Tags: c#, winapi, api, 64-bit, native

I use this code to iterate through native Windows Explorer menu from C#.

this is import of GetMenuItemInfo function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, int uItem,
                                  bool fByPosition, ref MENUITEMINFO lpmii);
```

with this code I iterate through menu:

```
int count = User32.GetMenuItemCount(menu);
var itemInfo = new MENUITEMINFO();

itemInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(itemInfo);
itemInfo.fMask = MIIM.MIIM_ID | MIIM.MIIM_STRING;

bool previousDeleted = false;

for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
{
   itemInfo.dwTypeData = new string(' ', 100);
   itemInfo.cch = 100;

   if(!User32.GetMenuItemInfo(menu, n, true, ref itemInfo))
   {
       Debug.Print("Error={0}",Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
   }

...
```

When I call this code from x86 application - it works perfectly,
But when I call this code from "Any CPU" application it is not working, and returns error code 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the GetMenuItemCount call succeeding? You should be checking count to see if it is -1.

Comment: Also, what is the MENUITEMINFO type you are creating on the 2nd line? Is that your own type or provided by the framework? I'm assuming it is your own as it has no namespace prefix, but maybe you've got a "using" statement we can't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using the wrong definition of `MENUITEMINFO`.  See here for the correct C# signature: [PInvoke MENUITEMINFO](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MENUITEMINFO.html?diff=y).  Look further down the page to see what you are probably using instead (e.g. hSubMenu).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a solution with 2 separate projects-wrappers for x86 and x64 platforms. There was an additional project with interfaces and a factory to resolve proper implementation at runtime.